# Ionic 2 - How change to specific platform style in the browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I would like to see how my app looks in android and in uwp too. How could I change that platform style when/before ionic loads? I would prefer a javascript solution, like setting some config variable during bootstrap.

I am pretty sure there is an official solution for that, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/

```
@App({
  template: `<ion-nav [root]="root"></ion-nav>`
  config: {
    mode: 'md'
  }
})
```

I just use chrome web inspector (view > developer > developer tools). you can then select OS and phone size in the top left corner (After clicking the mobile view button that is).

Comment: Using the config works perfectly, but it doesn't change the style based on the selected mobile device in the dev tools.

Comment: you may have to refresh the page once you select nexus vs. iphone or vice versa. plus the config will most likely override that feature if it is set